# Compare array column by column for number of matching rows

Tags: loops, duplicates

What is the best way to scan a 100 column by 1000 row array (with header) comparing each COLUMN to COLUMN 100, ROW by ROW, and report number of duplicate entries in each column. For example, I am showing columns 1-5 and Column100, and rows 1-4 of the array:

```
COL1 COL2 COL3 COL4 COL5 . COL100
0   1   0   2   1   .   2
0   1   2   1   0   .   1
1   2   0   0   0   .   0
.   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

The output should be:

Col1 has 0 duplicates (matches Col100 in 0 rows)

Col2 has 1 duplicates (matches Col100 in 1 rows)

Col3 has 1 duplicates (matches Col100 in 1 rows)

Col4 has 3 duplicates (matches Col100 in 3 rows)

Col5 has 1 duplicates (matches Col100 in 1 rows)

....and so on all the way to Col99. Perhaps a loop may be best.

or, the output can be in a 2 column by 100 row table such as:

```
COLUMN NO.  DUPLICATES ( Matches)
1   0
2   1
3   1
4   3
5   1
.   .
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What tool/language do you plan to use?  This could be handled in a SQL database, or with a stats language like R.

Comment: I’m very flexible. R is also ok.